# Ability to store assets outside of the website in cheaper storage

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, assets

I am trying to understand if there is a possibility to store assets outside of the folder structure of the website (outside the scope of codeigniter).

My current infrastructure is using CodeIgniter-2 with PHP 7.1 on a IIS Windows platform.

Comment: When you say outside of the folder structure you mean in another domain or in a folder is is outside the scope of codeigniter?

Comment: Yes sir outside the scope of codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can simply create a folder at the root of your installation (at the same level as the index.php file) and store whatever you want inside
You can also use .htaccess to protect access to this folder from http and from outside

cordially

Comment: Sorry for not explaining myself properly but I was thinking more of storing the assets in a different hard drive or S3 for example.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to access assets stores in a S3 instance you can use their SDK provided for PHP:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/s3-examples.html

There's even a few libraries on packagist that you can use for this:

https://packagist.org/packages/aws/aws-sdk-php

With a library like this, you can both access and send files to a S3 instance.

If what you want is to access files in another folder outside the scope of your codeigniter 2 in a windows platform you'll need to setup a mklink inside your codeigniter folder.

This will create what is called a symbolic link to the desired folder.

You can read more about that here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink

The syntax would be something like:

```
mklink [[/d] | [/h] | [/j]] <link> <target>
```